# For parfor, vertical concatenation of table is too slow

Tags: matlab

I am suffering from speed issue on vertical concatenation of tables, each of which is a part of parfor loop.

Here's what I do:

```
T = table(group1, group2, val1, val2, ...);
T = sortrows(T, {'group1', 'group2'}); % possible speed gains from sorting?
[Pairs, idx] = unique([T.group1, T.group2], 'rows');

idx1 = [idx; height(T)+1]; % to include the last index
idx2 = idx1(2:end) - 1;
idx1 = idx1(1:end-1);

T_ = [];
parfor i=1:length(Pairs)
    tmpIdx = idx1(i):idx2(i);
    T_ = T(tmpIdx, :);
    T__ = myFun(T_);
    T_ = [T_; T__];
end

function T_out = myFun(T_in)
    vlist = T_in.Properties.VariableNames;
    T_out = T_in(:, vlist) % preallocation

    % overwrite values
    for i = 1 : length(vlist)
        T_out.vlist(2:end, i) = T_in{1:end-1, vlist{i}};
    end
end
```

Inside `myFun()`, I do some calculations on `T.val1, T.val2...`. However, above is too slow. I checked the profiler and found out that most of the time is spent in

1) `T_=T(tmpIdx, :)` (`tabular.vertcat`)

2) `T_out.vlist(2:end, i) = T_.vlist{1:end-1, vlist{i}}` inside `myFun` (`tabular.subsasgn, tabular.subsref`)

For 1), despite its slow speed, I guess slicing `T` is inevitable as I'm calculating values w.r.t. unique pairs of `T.group1` and `T.group2`.

Though the main problem is 1), the time spent on 2) is also significant.

Any good ideas for improvements? Any comments/suggestions will be very much helpful.

Comment: Although I'm a big fan of using tables (primarily due to the ease in identifying columns), in my experience, indexing into them is slow, and if you have to index into them more than a handful of times you are better copying the data to a matrix (assuming all of the data in your table numeric is numeric) and manipulating the matrix, then reconstructing an output table at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @PhilGoddard. ```N > 1e+4``` here, which seems to be large enough. Maybe I should split the table into strings and numerics, do the calculations with numerics, and add labels at the end.